# Anyone know about 'Soundscapes for interiors and architecture' ???

Tags: soundscapes, psychoacoustics, art, research

I have this itching idea to research field of application of sound arts composed specifically for particular space - interior or can be called indoor dimensions, but can't find any studies that have been previously done on this subject. Eg what is the relations between different spaces and different sounds and how soundscape can be created for a specific place and enrich or highlight some of its aspects ?
Anything about this in the internet or books? Guess this has definitely something to do with psychoacoustics but just in general...

Thank you in advance colleagues

Comment: I MEAN 'ENVIRONMENTAL SOUND DESIGN'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens I do nearly all of the composition/sound design for Julian Treasure's The Sound Agency, happy to answer any questions you might have.

We've created soundscapes for banks, hotels, shops and even a small town. A lot of what I've done with Julian is designing ambient music for a specific space and we often install the speaker systems as well.

Is there something specific you're interested in?

Paul Weir

Comment: have a ton of questions: 1) When you see the space first time, what are your first thoughts? What aspects of sound-space relations do you pay attention to?
2) If you created just abstract sounds for lets say indoor pool (long and narrow rectangle, mirrored ceiling, blue and green colours are predominant in the space) what would it be and how you could start thinking about that?
3) Is there any written academic work on creating sound for environments ?
4) I assume you have absolute freedom of positioning speakers - how their placement linked with the space?
out of characters... to be continued

Comment: please could you answer those questions for my research?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe here....
http://www.juliantreasure.com/Julian_Treasure/Home.html

Comment: didn't get what you wanted to say by this really

Comment: I'm under the impression that this book describes acoustics and provides a guidline/strategy either philosophical or technical for designing a workspace around the effects of sound.

Answer (score 2):

You can really look at it in different ways. One is as Paul and Chris have highlighted. It can be used commercially for marketing and business purposes, but I have a feeling you're looking at it differently?

I studied Sound Art and my dissertation was about how sound and noise has dictated the way we live in our world. An example... Thames Barrier park in London is built with acoustics in mind, the park is raised above traffic to deflect harsh sounds and has fountains at the entrance to mask traffic with white noise. http://static.london.gov.uk/mayor/strategies/noise/docs/urbandes/14thamesbarrierpark.pdf

There are also schools in London which have been redeveloped with noise in mind as well as it being aesthetically pleasing to the eye/brain. There is even proof that it has improved grades. Here's more info on some projects in England which have done this. http://static.london.gov.uk/mayor/strategies/noise/

Acoustics make a massive change to how we perceive our spaces, you only need to walk into a huge cathedral to understand.

You don't have to make sound for it to be sound art/design :)

Also check out some sound sculptures which are purpose made for where they have been placed.  Singing, Ringing Tree by Tonkin Liu, http://youtu.be/Ve6PTrlLGOU A sound sculpture that the wind plays. Eerie sounds played by the executed witches that once inhabited the area? :P

Comment: yeah, I'm looking differently like to make sound art for a space that will be like a life and well-being support and how sound can be arranged with different places. 

Answer (score 0):

@Pretaeperon Have you found much more on this subject elsewhere?  This is something I am very interested in!

Comment: the material is extremely limited on this topic

Answer (score 0):

You're very welcome to mail me off-list if it'll help for your research, we've a number of interesting projects in the pipeline.

paulw@earcom.net

PaulW